# Software: files backup to ftp-server and built in scheduling?

Tags: backup, scheduling

I am looking for a program that will make scheduled backups to a specific ftp-server/folder. I have tried:

**Create Synchronizity**
Great for local backup and has scheduling, but lacks ftp. Can not recognize a mapped ftp-drive letter.

**AceBackup**
Has both scheduling and ftp backup, but the scheduling is not built-in but tries to utilize the scheduler in windows. And fails.

**EaseUS Todo Backup**
No ftp.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Iperius Backup seems to do the trick.

Aaaand now I look like a sales agent.